# Remove small objects -- Liver image segmentation

Tags: python, image-processing, object-detection, image-segmentation

I need to make a **liver image segmentation** starting from a matrix of *Hounsfield units* ([input-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvQor.png)) and a *mask approximation* of the liver ([input-mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e0Vy.png)).

After some processing, I ended up with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aZgc.png) representation of the liver. The main problem now is how to remove those **small objects** and keep only the *liver* in the image. I will explain what I did to obtain this image:

*1) Hounsfield thresholding + Normalization* - After this step, the image looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0ThZ.png)

```
def slice_window(img, level, window):
    low  = level - window / 2
    high = level + window / 2
    return img.clip(low, high)

# `hu_mat` is the input image
hu_mat_slice = slice_window(hu_mat, 100, 50)

def translate_ranges(img, from_range_low, from_range_high, to_range_low, to_range_high):
    return np.interp(img,
                    (from_range_low, from_range_high),
                    (to_range_low, to_range_high))

hu_mat_norm = translate_ranges(hu_mat_slice, hu_mat_slice.min(), hu_mat_slice.max(), 0, 1)
```

*2) ROI (Convex Hull) + Binarizing* - After this step, the image looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1nx7.png)

I tried to isolate the liver as much as I could by using the *initial mask approximation*. I generated the *Convex Hull* and kept only the points inside the convex hull.

```
def in_hull(hull, points, x):
    hull_path = Path(points[hull.vertices])
    # radius=25: "expands" the polygon; this ensures me the liver will not end up cutted
    return hull_path.contains_point(x, radius=25)

hu_mat_hull = np.zeros((len(hu_mat_norm), len(hu_mat_norm[0])))
for i in range(len(hu_mat_norm)):
    for j in range(len(hu_mat_norm[0])):
        if not in_hull(hull, points, (i, j)):
            hu_mat_hull[i][j] = 0
        else:
            hu_mat_hull[i][j] = hu_mat_norm[i][j]

threshold_confidence = 0.5
hu_mat_binary = np.array([[0 if el < threshold_confidence else 1 for el in row] for row in hu_mat_hull])
```

*3) Remove small objects*

For this part, I tried to use the some `morphology` for removing the small objects from the image:

```
from skimage import morphology
hu_mat_bool = np.array(hu_mat_binary, bool)
rem_small = morphology.remove_small_objects(hu_mat_bool, min_size=1000).astype(int)
```

I used different values for the `min_size` parameter, but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77BU0.png) is the best resulted image. Actually, it removes something, but very little. Those small objects which are close to the liver are ignored.

I've also tried to find contours in the image and keep only the largest one:

```
from skimage import measure
contours = measure.find_contours(hu_mat_orig_hull, 0.95)
```

The found contours are present [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWD9v.png). I tried to make a dilation starting from the small contours, but didn't succeed to remove the small objects from the image.

---

What else should I try in order to remove those small objects and generate a mask similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmg0a.png)?

Comment: After performing morphological operations, find the largest contour and draw it on another image. It can be done using OpenCV

Comment: I'm curious what library are you using for pre-processing?

Comment: I've used some classes from `skimage`, but I can also use other libraries if necessary.. I've tried to detect objects using the skimage, but didn't succeed.. it detects small groups of pixels instead of those group of 4 objects from the image (the largest object being the liver).. What could be some other ideas I can try?

Comment: You can try difference of Gaussians using different kernels and Sigma values. Also try adaptive threshold to isolate those 4 smaller regions